# DNS resolution failure when resolv.conf has nameserver value as 127.0.0.1

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, resolv.conf

We have an application hosted in 2 ec-2 instances. In an AWS Route 53 record of A type, the domain is mapped with the IP addresses of those 2 servers. From one of the local VM in our office network, when the application was accessed from a program it gave DNS resolution failed error. dig domainname +short also did not gave any output. nslookup command also reported NX domain error.

After some exploring, found that in resolv.conf file the Nameserver value was 127.0.0.1. When we changed it with some other values, like default name server 8.8.4.4 once and other local machine IP issue did not occur.

Also tried nslookup -q=A domainname 8.26.56.26.When the name server value was 127.0.0.1 in resolv.conf file, except for this Comodo(US) name server IP, for all the other ones ( Google, CloudFlare ) output was success.

Can we get some assistance on when does the resolv.conf gets changed in general and why issues occur when the value is 127.0.0.1

Comment: This sounds like the answer to "what happens if we stop/disable/remove the DNS service from this host in AWS?  You know, the server we setup so you could sinkhole some zones?"

Comment: Thank you Greg for looking into this. Can you please elaborate about 'the server we setup so you could sinkhole some zones'.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1616486/after-installing-dnsmasq-resolv-conf-changes-to-127-0-0-1

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link Greg. Based on this I understand that when a particular DNS server is installed, it may update the resolv.conf accordingly. 
One query: From where the network manager gets the required info to update resolv.conf